# Redirect URL towards a generic IP on router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I am looking for simple, clear instructions about how to add a rule on my router (home) that can forward the ping towards a url to a specific IP address (or other URL). Furthermore, I want that rule active ONLY for a specific device (read IP) in my LAN, not for all the devices connected.
This is the specific case: I own a TV HD CAM from Logitech that is able to connect the my LAN (wireless or wired), access to skype with an account and use it with my old not-smart TV through a HDMI. This product is old, and in order to check if internet connection with skype.com is ok, it pings www.skype.com.
BUT the ping goes wrong, so it stucks saying that internet connection doesn't work, while actually it works.
So I want that ONLY FOR THE CAM, when it pings to www.skype.com the router redirect its request to any ping that run (no matter which one), so that the cam thinks that everything is ok and keep running.

Thanks for any help you can provide me!

Comment: What is the model of your router?

Comment: Hi! This is my router: TP-LINK TD-W8968 (IT) Modem Router Wireless N 300Mbps, ADSL2+, Fast Ethernet, USB